# Getting selected item in ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView where I show a menu on the long click. In onContextItemSelected I have a logic to handle the action. I need to know what item in ListView is selected.

- If a user selects item that isn't a submenu, I can use MenuItem.getMenuInfo().
- But if a user selects a submenu, MenuItem.getMenuInfo() returns null.

What is the correct way how to determine the selected item if there's a submenu ?

The menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/Edit" android:title="Edit" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Settings" android:title="Settings">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/V1" android:title="V1" />
        ...
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

onContextItemSelected:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {
  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo AdapterInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)Item.getMenuInfo(); // getMenuInfo returns null if V1 is selected (submenu) but works if selected item isn't submenu, e.g., 'Edit' as per above XML
  UserItem SelectedItem = MyAdapter.getItem(AdapterInfo.position); // MyAdapter is the instance of class that inherits from ArrayAdapter<UserItem> i.e. adapter for ListView
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do 3 things

1.provide a default section in your switch statement that handles your menu items

2.save off the info.position to a member variable in your Activity

3.when you detect that info is null, use the var you created in step 2

```
private int mParentContextMenuListIndex;

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
        return false;
    }
    //if info == null, it means we have a submenu to deal with, use the saved info.position
    int idxOfList = (info!=null) ? info.position : this.mParentContextMenuListIndex;
    ...
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.context_menu_item_1:
            ... //use idxOfList instead of info.position
            return true;
        case R.id.context_menu_item_2:
            ... //use idxOfList instead of info.position
            return true;
        case R.id.context_menu_item_3:
            ... //use idxOfList instead of info.position
            return true;
        case R.id.context_submenu_item_1:
            ... //use idxOfList instead of info.position
            return true;
        case R.id.context_submenu_item_2:
            ... //use idxOfList instead of info.position
            return true;
        default: //can handle submenus if we save off info.position
            this.mParentContextMenuListIndex = idxOfList;
    }//switch
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `onItemClickLitener()` for all the items in you listview without dividing them on munu items and submenu items?

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String s = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            }
    });
```

So `i` will be your item position.

If you still want to work with submenu items you need to implement `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method and catch onclick events based on the **id** of submenu items .

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 10:
            //do smth here
            return true;
        case 15:
            //do smth here
            return true;
        case 20:
            //do smth here
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. When I try setOnItemClickListener, it's not firing.

Comment: if your list item is focusable and clickable or it has a focusable and clickable view as a child, on click listeners do not work. Making the item view non-focusable solves the problem. Set these properties to false everywhere